# Akka - how to configure to guarantee a message reaches another actor?

Tags: akka

Akka actors are based off fire and forget mechanism for exchanging messages, how can I configure Akka so that messages are guaranteed to be delivered to another actor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinary Akka actors, by its design principle, don't guarantee [message delivery](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/message-delivery-reliability.html).  Akka does however provide an at-least-once delivery option if you use its [PersistentActor](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/persistence.html).

At-least-once delivery essentially ensures that the persistent sender actor will keep sending messages to the receiver at a configurable frequency until it receives confirmation from the receiver (or from some termination routine for canceling ongoing delivery attempts).

With at-least-once delivery, persisted messages will be re-sent until receipt of confirmation.  Akka provides method `deliver` to send each message tagged with a consecutive monotonically increasing `deliveryId` and, upon receiving a confirmation with the corresponding `deliveryId` from the receiver, uses method `confirmDelivery` to signal successful delivery of the message.

The following Scala snippet, which is part of the sample code from the [Akka doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence.html?language=scala#at-least-once-delivery), highlights the key at-least-once delivery logic in the sender actor class (which `extends PersistentActor with AtLeastOnceDelivery`):

```scala
override def receiveCommand: Receive = {
  case s: String =>
    persist(MsgSent(s))(updateState)
  case Confirm(deliveryId) =>
    persist(MsgConfirmed(deliveryId))(updateState)
}

override def receiveRecover: Receive = {
  case evt: Evt => updateState(evt)
}

def updateState(evt: Evt): Unit = evt match {
  case MsgSent(s) =>
    deliver(destination)(deliveryId => Msg(deliveryId, s))
  case MsgConfirmed(deliveryId) =>
    confirmDelivery(deliveryId)
}
```

Note that the same persistence handler `updateState` is used to persist events corresponding to `deliver` and `confirmDelivery` for consistent state recovery.